# Согласование падежа

Tags: согласование

Добрый день, у меня возникли трудности в согласовании падежа в следующем предложении:

> И еще **три разнопрофильных специалиста** задавали вопросы по языкам программирования.

Правильно ли я согласовал падеж?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все правильно.

При существительных мужского и среднего рода, зависящих от числительных *два, три, четыре (а также от составных числительных, оканчивающихся на указанные цифры), определение, находящееся между числительным и существительным, в современном языке ставится, как правило, в форме родительного падежа множественного числа:* **два высоких дома, три больших окна, двадцать четыре деревянных стола**.

См.: [Справочник по литературному редактированию, Розенталь, Д.Э.](http://evartist.narod.ru/text1/65.htm#%D0%B7_03)

Comment: Спасибо. Так и звучит лучше, но я думал, что так неправильно.